# Windows Phone 7 Search Button

Tags: search, windows-phone-7

**BASED ON OUT DATED BETA**

Is there support for the Search Button yet in WinPhone 7 sdk?

I can't find it, nor anything info on it.  Just thought someone might know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way for a Windows Phone application to intercept key presses on the Search button.

Comment: Indeed the Search is not supported for Third-party applications in the Windows Phone 7 initial release - however it may be added in a future update.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202889%28v=VS.92%29.aspx#sectionToggle3 says "Search is built into the hardware and software of every Windows Phone. Developers cannot modify or change the behavior of the hardware Search button; when pressed, it will always launch the Bing search experience for the user to find content from anywhere on the device."

Comment: This is really a joke. You't override the Search action to search local content in your app?