# How do I hook the hardware search button on WP7

Tags: search, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 app that has a search page. I would prefer to hook the hardware search button rather than having to add search icons to the menu bar.

Has anyone figured out how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The hardware search button is not available for third-party applications in the current release. (Please refer [this thread for a similar question already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796304/windows-phone-7-search-button))