# How can I tell when the "search" button is clicked when I set InputScope to search?

Tags: windows-phone-7, sip, windows-phone

For Windows Phone. How can I tell when the "search" button is clicked when I set InputScope to search on a TextBox? Is there an event?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the `InputScope` is set to "Search", the "search" button is just a restyled "enter" button. So, assuming:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Search" KeyDown="SearchBox_KeyDown" />
```

the "search " button being pressed (on the SIP) can be detected with:

```
private void SearchBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        // Do search...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, would you mind helping me, I have the same scenario my code is exactly the same as what you answered here, however I do not have a Key.Enter option?

Comment: @user2042227 you're probably missing inclusion of the appropriate namespace (`using System.Windows.Input;`).

Answer (score 4):

In addition to what Matt has (correctly) answered, if you handle e.PlatformKeyCode == 0x0A (as shown below) you can also respond to the Enter key being pressed on the host keyboard when running in the emulator without the SIP.

```
if ((Key.Enter == e.Key) || (e.PlatformKeyCode == 0x0A))
{
    // Do search...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the hardware search button? It's not exposed.
 [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952256/how-do-i-hook-the-hardware-search-button-on-wp7)

Comment: The question refers to the search button on the InputScope, not the hardware button

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 8.1 Apps (not Silverlight) you may use VirtualKey

```
if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    //Do Something.
}
```