# WPF Search button function

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone 7 Search Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796304/windows-phone-7-search-button)

I think that all Windows Phone mobiles have a search button (phisical or not).

Actually, they have three buttons: `Back button`, `Windows Logo button`, `Search button`.

Is possible to modify the function of this button (as Back button). Something like `OnSearchKeyPress` (as event handler).

Its possible?

Comment: Do you mean WP7 instead of WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible, because that could seriously alter the behavior of the phone. There is a search task you can use, [for more info, see this MSDN article on it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202889%28v=VS.92%29.aspx#sectionToggle3)

Comment: It was what I thought. Forced.